# Error missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed when running metaMDS in R

Tags: r, distance, vegan

I am trying to perform an NMDS test using Bray-Curtis dissimilarity using metaMDS from the package *vegan*. See code:

`pc = read.csv("nmds.csv", header = TRUE) com = pc[,5:ncol(pc)]`   ###where 5 is the column where my info begins
`m_com = as.matrix(com) set.seed(123) nmds = metaMDS(m_com, distance = "bray")`

And this is what my data looks like:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrhrp.png)

However when I perform the last step (nmds = metaMDS(m_com, distance = "bray")) I get the following error:
`Error in if (max(dis) > maxdis + sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)) { :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning messages: 1: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) : you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method “bray” 2: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) : missing values in results`

I have used the same code for years and have never come across this problem. I saw in some threads it's because there are zeroes in my data but I've done this with data that contained zeroes before.

I used the same code on an old set of data that contained many zeroes (but much smaller set of data) and it was able to calculate it and give the solution (see result below).

```
Wisconsin double standardization Run 0 stress 0.1232691  Run 1 stress
0.1380158  Run 2 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002867434  max resid 0.002609401  ... Similar to previous best Run 3 stress
0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002975044  max resid 0.002720978  ... Similar to previous best Run 4 stress 0.2390168  Run 5 stress
0.1232696  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002939605  max resid 0.002594778  ... Similar to previous best Run 6 stress 0.1502755  Run 7 stress
0.1232693  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002335296  max resid 0.002429394  ... Similar to previous best Run 8 stress 0.1232691  ... New best solution ... Procrustes: rmse 2.084762e-06  max resid 1.672081e-05  ... Similar to previous best Run 9 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002904649  max resid 0.002643373  ... Similar to previous best Run 10 stress 0.1380158  Run 11 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse
0.0002872963  max resid 0.002608208  ... Similar to previous best Run 12 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002861628  max resid
0.002597991  ... Similar to previous best Run 13 stress 0.1232696  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.000292253  max resid 0.002573828  ... Similar to previous best Run 14 stress 0.2587088  Run 15 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002856807  max resid 0.002589665  ... Similar to previous best Run 16 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse
0.0002866945  max resid 0.002595448  ... Similar to previous best Run 17 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002864601  max resid
0.002605703  ... Similar to previous best Run 18 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.000295793  max resid 0.002704928  ... Similar to previous best Run 19 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse
0.0002905679  max resid 0.002632124  ... Similar to previous best Run 20 stress 0.1232695  ... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002865427  max resid
0.002612774  ... Similar to previous best
*** Best solution repeated 11 times
> nmds

Call: metaMDS(comm = m_com, distance = "bray") 

global Multidimensional Scaling using monoMDS

Data:     wisconsin(m_com)  Distance: bray 

Dimensions: 2  Stress:     0.1232691  Stress type 1, weak ties 
Best solution was repeated 11 times in 20 tries 
The best solution was from try 8 (random start) 
Scaling: centring, PC rotation, halfchange scaling  
Species: expanded scores based on ‘wisconsin(m_com)’
```

Why is it not working on my new dataset? I have verified that all boxes contain a value, even if it is zero. I'm confused as to why it's working on 1 data set but not another. Could it be due to the size of the file? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think the major reason for the problems is given in this line of your message:

Answer (score 1):

I assume that these lines of your original message give you the answer:

```r
Warning messages:
1: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) : you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method “bray” 
2: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) : missing values in results
```

Your new data has empty rows (no species present), and there is no way to calculate Bray-Curtis dissimilarity for them, but they are merged as missing distances. It is a warning when you calculate dissimilarities, but it is an error when you try to use them in `metaMDS`.

In principle, we could handle missing values in `metaMDS`, but we have not implemented user interface yet. However, all we could do in this case is to remove the empty rows. I suggest you do the same.

```r
tot <- rowSums(m_com)
m_com <- m_com[tot > 0, ]
```

Comment: Hi @Jari thanks for your answer. I tried this and it worked however I'm a little confused. My data does not have any empty rows or cells. All cells contain a numeric value. Are you able to explain what you mean? Thanks again.

Comment: If you calculated the rowsums, have a look at them. If the trick helped, there is a row with total 0 or negative. One confusing way of getting zero-row is that read.csv read one line more than you assumed, and there is a stray empty row at the bottom of your file. Has happened to me and is one thing that you always have to check after reading in data.